# Why would it be necessary to add a static bloc in a Java class?

Tags: java

Why would a person add a bloc in a Java class :

```
static {

   // ...
}
```

Could this have a bad result when having a web application?

Is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called [static initialization block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html), It's used to initialize static fields of a class.

> Could this have a bad result when having a web application?

No, Having static block won't give any harm, and it's depends on you.

> Is there any other alternative?

You can initialize static fields in the same line where you have declared them.

Comment: _"Having static block won't give any harm."_ Like any language construct, they can be abused, though. Depends on how they are used. For example, it's my experience that runtime exceptions thrown inside static initializers can be difficult to detect.

Comment: what about using the constructor? We can initialize in it as well... Why would we for example use static initialization instead of the constructor? Thanks!

Comment: @GotACrushOnIT : Constructor is for instances, static variable/methods are not belongs to instances, they are belong to Class, So initializing the Class property through instances will make you in troubles.

Answer (score 2):

> **Why would a person add a bloc in a Java class?**

For instance i had to once initialize my hashmap before i coud do anything else so i used static block for it 
Example:

```
public final static HashMap<String,Integer> messageTypes=new HashMap<>();

    static {//static initialization ..Loads before constructor 
        messageTypes.put("Report", REPORT_BOT);
        messageTypes.put("Scan", SCAN_BOT);
        messageTypes.put("Eat", EAT_BOT);
    }
```

This is just examplein addition to [Kugathasan Abimaran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22245522/515034)'s answer.